# How to convert a list of string into a list of floats in c#, unity?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, unity-game-engine

So I am querying data from a MySQL database, and I am storing the data in a JSON file. I have a list of string called 'x' that takes a row from the database, but the values themselves are float. I am trying to convert the list of string to a list of floats because I want to use those values as Vector Points.

My list string called 'x' is being called from another C# file where I am querying the database from PHP. How do I convert my list of string into a list of floats?

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataServerManager.instance.x.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(DataServerManager.instance.x);
}
```

What this code is doing is, it is going through my list of strings and debugging the values. The values are numbers. That is why I am trying to convert the list of string into a list of floats. Because I want to use these values as numbers.

The reason why they are in the list of strings in the first place is because of the JSON format.

How do I convert the list of strings into a list of floats?

Comment: How would you convert _one_ string to a float? Do that for all strings in your list of strings.

Comment: `List<Single> floats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select( str => ( ok: Single.TryParse( str, out Single f ), f ) ).Where( t => t.ok ).Select( t => t.f ).ToList()`

Comment: @Dai thank you so much!

Comment: @Dai, Hey, how do I convert a list of floats to a float. I need to use each and every one of these floats in my Vector3 vectorpoint variable. But when I use floats, it says cannot convert <float> to float. 
How do I convert the list of float into floats that i can use in my vector?

Comment: "it says cannot convert <float> to float" <-- That is not an actual compiler error message. Please post the **actual** error.

Comment: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<float>' to 'float'

Comment: @newbedecor and can you tell me what sort of float you'd expect from trying to convert this list of floats to just one float (or vector3): [1.1,2.2,3.3,4,4,5,5] - how do you convert them all to just a float? Add them up? Average them? Take the median? Take a random one? You can't just "convert from list of numbers to number"

Comment: I presume, as this is gaming, that these are some 3d coordinates and if you have eg 3 floats and want one vector3 then you make your vector using the list `f` like an array. `f[0],f[1],f[2]`. Please also note that stackoverflow is not a forum; you don't ask one question and then constantly ask more unrelated questions in the comments, building up a thread thousands of comments long as you get help with every part of the app you're developing. If you have a question like "I have a list of 3 floats,how do I turn it into a 3d point as a Vector" then hit Ask Question button and ask it as a new Q

Comment: i figured it out!thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your strings are reliably floaty and won't fail to parse you can do:

```
var floats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select(float.Parse).ToList()
```

If they might fail a parse, I think I'd use a loop

```
var floats = new List<float>();
foreach(var s in DataServerManager.instance.x)
  if(float.TryParse(s, out var f)) floats.Add(f);
```

Comment: thank you, I was able to figure out with @Dai help. They told me to use 'List<Single> floats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select( str => ( ok: Single.TryParse( str, out Single f ), f ) ).Where( t => t.ok ).Select( t => t.f ).ToList()'

Comment: That isn't how stack overflow works. Dai made that as a comment but it should have been posted as an answer. The placeholder text for the comment box even says "avoid answering questions in comments". I've posted (as an answer) two alternatives to Dai's suggestion - one that is simpler/faster if you're sure that all your strings will convert to float without error, and one that does check but does not use LINQ. You should not paste code into your program that you do not understand. The reason we should post answers instead of answering in comments is that comments are ephemeral and also..

Comment: ..cannot be marked as answers so your question remains "unanswered" on the dashboard and the rest of the community and future visitors have no good idea of what worked for you. SO is not just about you and your problem, it's about all the people who come here (to this very question) in the future. What you should do now is either ask Dai to post the comment as an answer, post your own answer or (as is indicated by your compiler error about floats that you might be using one of my suggestions) mark this answer as the answer by clicking the grey check to turn it green. This marks the Q answered

Comment: which helps guide future visitors as to what worked for you and also makes the dashboard work more effectively so that people hunting for unanswered questions have an easier time. In future if someone answers a question on a comment, don't use it and then leave your question to rot; ask them to post an answer or post your own -